# Which shader file format should I use in HLSL?

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I've read this DirectX 11 tutorial on VS2015 (http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut04.html), and found out that the author compiles the vertex and pixel shader separately, using the .vs file and .ps file respectively.

And I also found out that in the book "3D Game Programming with DirectX 11" the author use .fx file to organize the shaders throughout the book.

Which method should I use to develop my direct3D program with the latest version of Windows SDK, I wonder? Since I've heard that the Effects11 framework might be deprecated in the future.

Comment: See [this thread](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) for a discussion of Effects 11 'status'

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `fx` targets for new projects, and opt for per-stage compilation instead.  Note that this is independent of whether you actually put your shader code in separate files, though having one `.vs` or `.ps` per shader is a common convention.  Full D3D11 support for effects profiles (i.e. `fx_5_0`) is already deprecated in the latest (Windows 10) compiler, and there is no `fx_5_1` at all (some [directx-12](/questions/tagged/directx-12) features require shader model 5.1).

Comment: What do you mean 'per-stage compilation'? Don't load precompiled effect files and compile at runtime?

Comment: @StefanAgartsson Per-stage compilation as in compiling `?s_5_[0/1]`, where `?` is one of `v`ertex, `p`ixel, `g`eometry, `h`ull, `d`omain, or `c`ompute. This is in contrast to the `fx` profile which is used to encapsulate a combination of multiple shader stages as a *technique*.  Compilation should still be done offline, at build-time.

Comment: that is to say,always compile the .fx in build-time? I really don't know, besides .fx includes all the shaders while .vs or .ps describes a single shader,  what's other difference between those two?

Comment: See [this thread](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551307) for a longer explanation of ``fx`` vs ``hlsl`` files.